# zend framework 2 - tablegateway join, where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, sql, join, zend-framework2

I would like to join many tables by tablegateway. It works fine but when I join some table with the same column name Zend throw error like that:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id_club' in where clause is ambiguous
```

my code looks like this:

```
    $id = $pId_club;
    $result = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($id){
        $select->join('vm_position', 'id_position = vm_position.id', array('name'))
               ->join('vm_club', 'id_club = vm_club.id', array('club_name'))
               ->join('vm_user', 'id_user = vm_user.id', array('login'))
               ->join('vm_squad', 'id_club = vm_squad.id_club', array())
               ->where(array('id_club' => $id))
               ->order('id_user ASC');
    });
    $row = $result->current();
    return $row;
```

I have column `id_club` in the main table - `'vm_match'` and in `'vm_squad'`. Without joining `'vm_squad'` it works well.

Comment: You need to use the table name, or alias, when referring to a column name that appears in multiple tables involved in your query.

Comment: I think you need to remove the where clause, it is redundant in the query.

Comment: `>join('vm_squad', 'wm_match.id_club = vm_squad.id_club', array())`

Comment: @shukshin.ivan it doesn't work

Comment: I think @shukshin.ivan forgot `->where(array('vm_match.id_club' => $id))`